# C# SearhBox (Multiselect page) XAMARIN

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, searchbar

I have an `ObservableCollection` with a list of users' data which is wrapped for `multiselect` page.

I added `SearchBar` to the `multiselect` page but I cannot make it work.

**Code**

```
public class WrappedItemSelectionTemplate : ViewCell
        {
            public WrappedItemSelectionTemplate() : base()
            {
                Label Title = new Label() { TextColor = Color.Black };
                Title.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Item.Title"));
                Label Email = new Label() { FontSize = 14 };
                Email.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Item.Email"));

                Switch mainSwitch = new Switch() { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End };
                mainSwitch.SetBinding(Switch.IsToggledProperty, new Binding("IsSelected"));
                StackLayout Stack = new StackLayout();
                Stack.Children.Add(Title);
                Stack.Children.Add(Email);
                Grid grid = new Grid();
                grid.Children.Add(Stack, 0,0);
                grid.Children.Add(Email, 0, 1);
                grid.Children.Add(mainSwitch, 1, 0);
                View = grid;
            }
        }
        public List<WrappedSelection<T>> WrappedItems = new List<WrappedSelection<T>>();

        public SelectMultipleBasePage(List<T> items)
        {
            WrappedItems = items.Select(item => new WrappedSelection<T>() { Item = item, IsSelected = false }).ToList();
            ListView mainList = new ListView()
            {
                ItemsSource = WrappedItems,
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(WrappedItemSelectionTemplate)),
            };

            mainList.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.SelectedItem == null) return;
                var o = (WrappedSelection<T>)e.SelectedItem;
                o.IsSelected = !o.IsSelected;
                ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; //de-select
            };

            // SearchBar added
            StackLayout Stack = new StackLayout();
            SearchBar Search = new SearchBar(); 
            Stack.Children.Add(Search);
            Stack.Children.Add(mainList);
            Search.TextChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                SearchBar_TextChanged();
            };
            Content = Stack;

            void SearchBar_TextChanged()
            {
                //string keyword = Search.Text;
                //mainList.ItemsSource =
            }
        }
```

When I used `SearchBar` in my cases before I was using  `new ObservableCollection` for `ItemsSource` of my `ListView`, it was filtering it as I required.

But now am stuck and don't know how I can use the `SearchBar` for the field `Title` in that case with `WrappedItems`?

Answer (score 0):

Although I prefer to see the code in Xaml and bound to VM with MVVM binding to make it easier to read . But I think I got what you need.
What you need to :

1. Search within `WrappedItems`   and save the found result
2. Clear the ItemSource of the list view `mainList.ItemSource.Clear();`
3. Go through the foundItems and `mainList.ItemSource.Add(foundItem);`
4. If the Key is empty string "" then you go through original list and do the same work (i.e. clear the itemsource and add the whole data )